# Connect micro gearmotor to 5V battery

Tags: batteries, motor, pololu

Would 3 motors (like this one http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/993) connected to a 5V battery (like this one http://www.dx.com/p/59438) work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motors are rated for 6 V and that battery power supply for 5 V.  The motors should definitely spin at 5 V unloaded, but will produce less torque and lower top speed than if they were run at 6 V.  Beyond that, it's impossible to say what you think "work" means.

Answer (score 0):

What's your definition of "work"? If you mean hook it up and have the motor spin, then yes, it will work. Unless there's some sort of specific parameter you're concerned about (battery life, speed in RPM, etc), I don't understand the question.

Comment: Yes, by "work" I meant a decent spinning, not necessarily the maximum available one. I'm concerned about battery lifetime as well.